# modal is triggered when i go to another page

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

i have three buttons (view,update,delete) , the view button is an href that goes to another page and brings an id with it, while my update triggers a modal. my problem is that when i click the view button it goes to the other page but it also triggers the update modal.

home.php

```
<?php
foreach($schedRow as $row)
 {
      ?>   
                       <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['subject_db']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['section_db']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['sched_day']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php $stime=$row['start_time']; 
                          $etime=$row['end_time']; echo "".date('h:i a',strtotime($stime))." ~ ".date('h:i a',strtotime($etime))."";?></td>
                          <td> 
                            <a href="view.php?viewid=<?php echo $row['sched_id'];?>" class="btn btn-info">View</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"  
                            data-target="#updateModal-<?php echo $row['sched_id']; ?>">Update</a>
                            <a href="home.php?deleteid=<?php echo $row['sched_id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

                            <?php include'modal_update_sched.php'; ?>

                          </td> 

                        </tr>
                        <?php
                      }
                      ?>
```

heres the id of my modal

```
id="updateModal-<?php echo $row['sched_id']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it, the problem is that i called the modal in my view.php thats why it keeps triggering, note that i separated the code for my modal in another php file named modal_update_sched.php , i somewhat had an include 'modal_update_sched.php'; in my view.php, deleting it solved my problem.